# Loading Correct Index File

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

I'm trying to figure out how to tell Netbeans to load the index file that is inside of my public_html folder when the project is ran and I'm not sure how to.

Sources : http://screencast.com/t/kWMCRKOWoo

[image]

Run Configuration : http://screencast.com/t/SqZTN7Pu

[image]

**EDIT :**

Can anybody expand on the answer below? Any additional ideas with seeing my two screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can via localhost only run files inside

```
 http://localhost/WrestlingManager/index.php
```

and that is mapped to

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs\WrestlingManager\index.php
```

and that's what you have set in your run configuration.

It's easy if you can run in a browser (for example).

```
 http://localhost/WrestlingManager/public_html/index.php
```

If you want to run files from another location . You must that folder have in your `server conf file`

```
Alias /public_html = "C:/Netbeans/Projects/PhpApp1/public_html"
```

from my Apache httpd.conf

```
Alias /samples "D:/mysamples/xysamples"
<Directory "D:/mysamples/xysamples">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
   Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now I can : `http:/localhost/samples`

I can not see the real path of the `public_html` folder inside of your Netbeans project .

In Run configuration you can set

- Project URL :  `http://localhost/WrestlingManager/public_html/`
- Index File  :  index.php

Comment: I was hoping to change the web root so that its pointed to the public_html folder but its disabled for some reason. You can see the public_html folder in the first screen shot in my initial post.

Comment: @user2576961 : Show us the the real path of your public_html folder.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\WrestlingManager\public_html\  I need that to be the web root.

Comment: That's what you need ! But what you get in a browser with `http://localhost/WrestlingManager/public_html/index.php` ??

Comment: I get what I'm supposed to however whenever I've been able to point to the public_html folder as a web root it would normally do it as http://localhost/WrestlingManager/ so I would never see the public_html folder in the url. So I never had to make a route to take it off. I didn't think that would be a difference between doing it live vs. local server.

Comment: So map in your httpd.conf `Alias /WrestlingManager = "C:/xampp/htdocs/WrestlingManager/public_html/"` . Shutdown and restart Apache

Comment: It just like for a localhost you have to deal with some many more issues.

Comment: Already have an publicfolder! It is `C:/xampp/htdocs` . Why do you still want a puplic_html folder within a public folder. Think about your project design. Create a new project from existing source . Create the project outside of htdocs. In Project properties source check copy files and let netbeans copy it to your web root WestlingManager folder.

Comment: I'm just saying that sounds like I'll have to make adjustments when I go to upload this project live.

Comment: No you don't have. If you have a clean `WrestlingManager` within htdocs , you copy only the files from `localhost/WrestlingManager` to `http://myserver.com/WrestlingManager` .

Answer (score 2):

1. Rightclick on the project in the project explorer.
2. Click `Properties`.
3. Select `Run Configurations` under categories section.
4. Update the `Project url` & `Index file` fields.
5. Done ! :)

Update `Project folder` & `Source folder` too under sources category if those are incorrect.

Comment: With the project url and index file fields how should they look as well as the project folder and source folder because to the best of my knowledge they should have been correct.

Comment: To which url it is getting directed, when you click run button ?

Comment: Can you please provide the screenshot of run configuration tab too ?

Comment: well, this seems to be strange. Make sure there is no redirection setup in your .htaccess file.

Comment: It was too big to include in the comments so I'm including a link to a pastebin of my htaccess file. http://pastebin.com/cu7ZVJdy